# Подскажите как использовать sass файлы в next.js

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, node-sass

Я привык писать так:

```
components/Nav.jsx
components/Nav.scss
```

Nav.jsx

```
import './Nav.scss';
const Nav = () => {
   return (
      <nav>
         <a href="#">Test</a>
      </nav>
   );
}
```

И Next.js мне выбивает ошибку, что надо использовать модульность.
Ошибка:

```
./components/Nav.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to pages\_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
```

Но я придерживаюсь Flux архитектуре, и мне моим способом привычнее и удобней. Не уже ли нельзя так?
Зависимости

```
next, react, react-dom, sass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так попробуйте:

Переименовать `./Nav.scss` -> `./Nav.module.scss`

```
import styles from './Nav.module.scss'
const Nav = () => {
   return (
      <nav>
         <a href="#" className={styles.error}>Test</a>
      </nav>
   );
}
```

Nav.module.scss:  (пример)

```
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Ошибок нет, но стили не применяются(

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо сначало изменить файл next.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
}
```

А затем подключать стили через модули